# larvavel 5 language file with html <br>

Tags: php, localization, laravel-5

I have a button in my site where the text shall be on 2 lines. The text in the button is populated by translation feature `trans()` with the content provided by the language files.

Now I face the problem when I enter HTML, in this case `<br>`, in the language file, it will be escaped and not be parsed.

#### resources/lang/en/messages.php

```php
return [
'iamaclown' = 'I am a<br>clown', 
//...
];
```

#### resources/views/foo.blade.php

```php
<button>{{ trans( 'messages.iamaclown' ) }}</button>
```

This gives me the output

```
I am a<br> clown
```

But I want

```
I am a 
clown
```

**Is there a way to accomplish that?**

Comment: `{!! trans( 'messages.iamaclown' ) !!}` ?

Comment: Top. Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display unescaped data, wrap the `trans( 'messages.iamaclown' )` in

`{!! trans( 'messages.iamaclown' ) !!}`

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
The name of the website is, {!! $websiteName!!}.
```

**Note:** Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to escape any HTML entities in the content.